# Is there a way to un-nock an arrow in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I nock arrows at the slightest provocation or thought of danger.  As a result, I frequently have a nocked arrow and don't need to fire it.  I don't want to waste it, but I don't like my current method of firing at my feet.

How can I un-nock an arrow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply choose a different item in your inventory.

Answer (score 6):

Either select another item/tool or fire the arrow into the floor/ceiling/wall near you and pick it up.

Comment: The issue is that there is a chance the arrow will be destroyed on contact.

Comment: Arrows are only destroyed by hitting entities. As long as you're aiming at a block, you can always pick up the arrow again. On the other hand, it does wear out the bow.

Answer (score 2):

Simply scroll with your mouse while still nocking the arrow (holding the mouse button): this will select a different item in your inventory.